Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 24 cannot be smaller than version 25 declared in library
when ever i run the app it gives the same error
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 24 cannot be smaller than version 25 declared in library [androidx.wear.compose:compose-foundation:1.3.1] C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\transforms-4\ffb6e3f0b4d3a53a60d0b9b4d73fac69\transformed\compose-foundation-1.3.1\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 24
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 24,
or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 25,
or use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.wear.compose.foundation" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
enter image description here
i am trying to make a simple app, in which if we click the box it changes the color. but it is giving this error to me.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
